# Stop a YouTube embed video

Tags: video, youtube

To embed a YouTube video and make it begin to a specific second I can add &start=25 at the end of the src like in the example. My question is: is there any way I can stop the video at a specific minute? (of course &stop=45 does not work)

Here I have the example to try: http://jsfiddle.net/79cd2/

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/AmAmK6HlYAY?rel=0&start=25" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Use "end"

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/AmAmK6HlYAY?rel=0&start=25&end=32" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```